# Is there any easy way to trigger same instance method after different custom callbacks in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, rails-models

Consider my model to be like this:

```
class SampleProject < ActiveRecord::Base

    #consider all these callbacks to be custom defined ones
    #I'm using default callbacks just to explain my problem

    after_save :simple_testing
    after_update :simple_testing
    before_save :simple_testing
    before_create :simple_testing
    after_commit :simple_testing

    def simple_testing
       #my custom code
    end

end
```

So here the same method is being invoked after all the call backs. So is there any simple way to define that all this callbacks should evoke *simple_testing* method ?

Comment: `simple_testing` is going to get called three times when you create a SampleProject record - is that what you want to happen?

Comment: It's not like that. Actually simple_testing is called in my custom callback methods not in the default callback methods. I know what I've written as example code here is absurd, but this is just to give the idea only. @MaxWilliams Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  Generally i find it's best to use your actual code: when you "translate" it into the "example" code you're liable to add confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Point noted. Next time onwards I will try to follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would ever want to do this, but remember you can use Ruby code anywhere in your class definition.

```
callbacks = [:after_save, :after_update, :before_save, :before_create, after_commit]
callbacks.each do |callback|
  self.send(callback, :simple_testing)
end
```

I've not tried this but it should work i think.